# How to get WooCommerce Order data before submission?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

We are using a 3rd party plugin to handle payments for WooCommerce called Klarna Checkout Version 2.

Klarna Checkout shows an `iframe` hosted from their domain after adding a product to cart.

[image]

Since I cannot write jQuery to get the data of the `iframe form` hosted from another domain, I am thinking of a **woocommerce hook** to get data.

I tried the code below but I get no data:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'show_klarna_data');
function show_klarna_data($posted_data) {
    global $woocommerce;
    print_r($posted_data);
}
```

Do you know how can I **return data** from woocommerce like reviewing an order before submission?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hello you mean this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845356/how-do-i-apply-discount-on-woocommerce-total-after-adding-product-to-cart ? Not yet..

Comment: Can you please write your answer for the new link..

Comment: The ajax request to call the new_customer_discount() in functions.php works..

Comment: I can already determine if a customer is new, my current problem is to call a hook properly to update the total price even if add_to_cart is already finished..

Answer (score 2):

Hello you need to call woocommerce hook `woocommerce_checkout_process` to get data before process payment on checkout.use below code will do the trick.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'get_woo_cart_detail', 10);

    function get_woo_cart_detail()
    {
        $items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

        foreach ($items as $item => $values)
        {
            $_product = $values['data']->post;
            $product_title = $_product->post_title;
            $qty = $values['quantity'];
            $price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'], '_price', true);
        }
    }
```

Code goes in your active theme's function.php

You could also get data like this using `cart object` if you are using woocommerce version below 3.0

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ){
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id']; // Product ID
    $product_obj = wc_get_product($product_id); // Product Object
    $product_qty = $cart_item['quantity']; // Product quantity
    $product_price = $cart_item['data']->price; // Product price
    $product_total_stock = $cart_item['data']->total_stock; // Product stock
    $product_type = $cart_item['data']->product_type; // Product type
    $product_name = $cart_item['data']->post->post_title; // Product Title (Name)
    $product_slug = $cart_item['data']->post->post_name; // Product Slug
    $product_description = $cart_item['data']->post->post_content; // Product description
    $product_excerpt = $cart_item['data']->post->post_excerpt; // Product short description
    $product_post_type = $cart_item['data']->post->post_type; // Product post type

    $cart_line_total = $cart_item['line_total']; // Cart item line total
    $cart_line_tax = $cart_item['line_tax']; // Cart item line tax total
    $cart_line_subtotal = $cart_item['line_subtotal']; // Cart item line subtotal
    $cart_line_subtotal_tax = $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax']; // Cart item line tax subtotal

    // variable products
    $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id']; // Product Variation ID
    if($variation_id != 0){
        $product_variation_obj = wc_get_product($variation_id); // Product variation Object
        $variation_array = $cart_item['variation']; // variation attributes + values
    }
}
```

Comment: @raju_wee Does your code above able to get the data of the checkout form?

Comment: It will get data before checkout processed.

Comment: can you please show how to ouput the billing address like the email and the address?